# Cube root in $ C^{*}$-algebra.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*\text{-algbera}$ and $x\in A$. I'm trying to show that
a)for $0<\alpha<\frac{1}{2}$, there exists $u\in A$ with $x=u(x^*x)^{\alpha}$ and $u^*u=(x^*x)^{1-2\alpha}$.
 b) there exists $y\in A$ such that $x=yy^*y$ ($\text{"cube root"}$ of x) and such $y$ is unique.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is this a homework?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, Yes, its form a homework.

Comment: I would start with the polar decomposition. But this is really just a guess. Try to understand the case $A=\mathbb{C}$ and try to generalize it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the proof of first part see [$C^*$-algebras and their automorphisms group by G. K. Pedersen](http://www.eknigu.com/info/M_Mathematics/MC_Calculus/MCf_Functional%20analysis/Pedersen%20G.K.%20C-algebras%20and%20their%20authomorphism%20groups%20%28AP,%201979%29%28600dpi%29%28T%29%28ISBN%200125494505%29%28426s%29.djvu) pages 11-12, lemmas 1.4.4-1.4.5.

For the proof of the second part use previous result with $\alpha=1/3$. Then you get $u\in A$ such that $x=u(x^*x)^{1/3}$ and $u^*u=(x^*x)^{1/3}$. Hence $x=uu^*u$. Proof of uniqueness I leave to you since this is a homework.

Comment: Thank you for your help, This is a great answer.

Comment: can you explain how to use lemma 1.4.5 to get what we want, because I already knew this fact, but could not figure this question, thank you.

Comment: I mean if we have $x=u(x^*x)^{\alpha}$ how can I find the form of $u^*u$?

Comment: In your case $a=x^*x$,, so $a^*=a$ and $u_n^*u_n=a^{1/2-\alpha}(n^{-1}+a)^{-1/2}a(n^{-1}+a)^{-1/2}a^{1/2-\alpha}$. After that $u^*u=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}u_n^*u_n$

Comment: @julien, because of my second and third comments, I did not see how to use this lemma to get the proof of the first part, but it still a great answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @i.a.m since $a$ is self adjoint then (by continuous functional calculus) so $a^{1/2-\alpha}$ and $(n^{-1}+a)^{-1/2}$. Hence $$\begin{align}u_n^*&=a^{1/2-\alpha}(n^{-1}+\alpha)x^*\\u_n^*u_n&=a^{1/2-\alpha}(n^{-1}+\alpha)^{-1/2}x^*x(n^{-1}+a)^{-1/2}a^{1/2-\alpha}\\&=a^{1/2-\alpha}(n^{-1}+\alpha)^{-1/2}a(n^{-1}+a)^{-1/2}a^{1/2-\alpha}\end{align}$$ Since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}u_n=u$, then $u^*u=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}u_n^*u_n$.

Comment: By Dini's theorem
$f_n(t)=t^{1/2-\alpha}(n^{-1}+t)^{-1/2}t(n^{-1}+t)^{-1/2}t^{1/2-\alpha}$
uniformly converges to $t^{1-2\alpha}$, then 
$$
u^*u=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}u_n^*u_n=a^{1-2\alpha}=(x^*x)^{1-2\alpha}
$$

Comment: @Norbert THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: @i.a.m you are wellcome!